# iOS Mail & Gmail Account, How to flag on swipe?

Tags: iphone, mail.app, gmail

I would like to flag/star email when swiping left. Is it possible with gmail account in iOS mail app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only change what a right swipe does in iOS. You can change what the middle option on a left swipe is, but a full left swipe will still be delete/archive.

Check out settings -> mail, contacts and calendar -> swipe options.

Answer (score 0):

Swiping left gives you three options, with the middle option being customizable.

You cannot change the left swipe to have only *one* option, unfortunately - it is built into iOS.

The middle option of the left swipe can be set to `Flag` if you so choose, leaving you with a swipe-tap motion.